# AspectJ - is there a way to 'hack' a static final field?

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

Say I have `private final static int N = 1` in class A

Is there any chance to 'hack' so that N becomes 2(without touching the source file A.java)?

The `set` pointcut seems not work on these `final` fields.

The thing is, I have the source code of some project, and I'm making some modifications to it to deploy it in our region. I'm trying to make these changes without touching the source file unless I have to.

@VinceEmigh reflection wouldn't work in my case. The source code looks like:

```
class MyClass
  private final static String[] NAMES = {"Name1", "Name2", "Name3"};

  public void createIsland() {
      //something
      int i = getNumberOfIsland();
      String name = NAMES[i];
      createIslandWithName(name);
      //something
  }
end
```

The thing is I need to change those hard coded `NAMES` to something else

Comment: What would be the point of `final` fields if you were allowed to change values (for primitives, as in your case) or references?

Comment: The first problem is that anything referring to that field will have the constant value baked into it, so changing the value of the field at execution time wouldn't affect that code. Fundamentally, this seems like a bad idea to me. What concrete problem are you trying to solve? I suspect you should take a step back and redesign.

Comment: Check this out, might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301635/change-private-static-final-field-using-java-reflection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Sample driver class:**

```
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
    private final static String[] NAMES = { "Name1", "Name2", "Name3" };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (String name : NAMES)
            System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

**Aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import de.scrum_master.app.Application;

public aspect ConstantChanger {
    Object around() : get(* Application.NAMES) {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPointStaticPart);
        return new String[] { "Hack1", "Hack2", "Hack3", "Hack4", "Hack5" };
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
get(String[] de.scrum_master.app.Application.NAMES)
Hack1
Hack2
Hack3
Hack4
Hack5
```

This way you change the array size as well as its content. Is that what you need?